# Unable to override bean property between processors in apache camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-camel

I am receiving json payload from another api, process it and write it in a file.
I also need to write header and footer records along with json payload as body.
The file name has to be some static text and some values that are coming from the json payload.(ex: A_20171113170000_seq_no_XXX_T_no_of_records.SAP)
The header has some static values and some properties(sequence number, timestamp and no of records) needs to be set dynamically based on the json payload.
I have to create 2 more files from another 2 end points. header and footer values will be dynamic for these files as well.
How do I pass the file name outside of processor so that I can write the file dynamically?

```
@Autowired
private Header header;

private Trailer footer;

private String file_name;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public final void configure() {
    
    LocalDateTime myDateObj = LocalDateTime.now();
    logger.info("Before formatting: " + myDateObj);
    DateTimeFormatter myFormatObj = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    String formattedDate = myDateObj.format(myFormatObj);
    
    String year = formattedDate.substring(0, 4);
    String month = formattedDate.substring(5, 7);
    String day = formattedDate.substring(8, 10);
    String hour = formattedDate.substring(11, 13);
    String minute = formattedDate.substring(14, 16);
    String second = formattedDate.substring(17);
    
    String dateString = year+month+day;
    String timeString = hour+minute+second;
    try {
        restConfiguration().component("jetty").port(httpPort).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);
        rest("/api/bcr/getResponseFromMax")
        .get().consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .route()
        .log("return response from max")
        .setBody()
        .constant("return response from max");
        
        final DataFormat basicPayBindy = new BindyFixedLengthDataFormat(BasicPay.class);
        

        rest("/api/bcr/basicpay")
        .post().consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).type(BasicPayResults.class).outType(ResponseEntity.class).route()
        .process(
                ex -> {
                    BasicPayResults result = ex.getIn().getBody(BasicPayResults.class);
                    List<BasicPay> employee = result.getResults();
                    file_name = Constants.FILE_NO+"_"+dateString+timeString+"_"+Constants.EMP+result.getSequenceNumber()+"_"+Constants.G2I+".SAP";
                    header.setHeader7(Constants.FILE_NO+"_"+dateString+timeString+"_"+Constants.EMP+result.getSequenceNumber()+"_"+Constants.G2I+".SAP");
                    logger.info("getSequenceNumber - "+result.getSequenceNumber()+" | file_name - "+file_name);
                    header.setHeader8(dateString);
                    header.setHeader9(timeString);
                    header.setHeader10(Constants.ENVIRONMENT);
                    
                    footer = new Trailer("TRAILER",(employee.size()+2));
                    ex.getOut().setBody(employee);
                    
                })
        .log("add trailer to the file")
        .process(
                ex -> {
                    logger.info(header.getHeader1()+" | "+header.getHeader2()+" | "+header.getHeader3()+" | "+header.getHeader4()+" | "+header.getHeader5()
                    +" | "+header.getHeader6()+" | "+header.getHeader7()+" | "+header.getHeader8()+" | "+header.getHeader9()+" | "+header.getHeader10()+" | "+header.getHeader11());
                    Map<String, Object> headerObjMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    headerObjMap.put(Header.class.getName(), header);
                    logger.info(" *** file_name 1 - "+file_name);
                    Map<String, Object> footerObjMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
                    footerObjMap.put(Trailer.class.getName(), footer);
                    
                    ex.getOut().setHeader(BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.CAMEL_BINDY_FIXED_LENGTH_HEADER, headerObjMap);
                    ex.getOut().setBody(ex.getIn().getBody());
                    ex.getOut().setHeader(BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.CAMEL_BINDY_FIXED_LENGTH_FOOTER, footerObjMap);
                    
                })
        .marshal(basicPayBindy)
        .convertBodyTo(byte[].class, "iso-8859-1")
        .setBody(body().regexReplaceAll("\\|", "\\|\""))
        .to("file:app/bcr-files?fileName="+header.getHeader7())
        .end();
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, you are mutating singleton instance of `Header`, so your app will not work correctly with two parallel requests, right? Just store everything request-scoped in Exchange property or header and dont mess with your class variables like you have now (header, footer, file_name). You can then use that with `toD` in your producer endpoint.

Comment: Hi Bedla, Yes I understand that I can't override header as it's a singleton object when autowired. I tried various things from auto populate header with static values and dynamically setting values. I stand corrected that I instantiate a new header object (when dynamically change the properties, if it's static I autowire) just like how I instantiated footer inside the process and add it to the exchange object. Anyway I found the answer. ex.getOut().setHeader() will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for the question.

We can pass the values through the header and access them outside the process.
Make sure you set it in the same method as the other values.
For example in the below code, I set the body, header and footer values in the ex.getOut().
Initially I tried it in ex.getIn() but it didn't work. So in order to pass the file name we need to set it in ex.getOut() instead of ex.getIn().

```
ex.getOut().setHeader(BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.CAMEL_BINDY_FIXED_LENGTH_HEADER, headerObjMap);
ex.getOut().setBody(employee);
ex.getOut().setHeader(BindyFixedLengthDataFormat.CAMEL_BINDY_FIXED_LENGTH_FOOTER, footerObjMap);
ex.getOut().setHeader("file_name1", file_name1);
```

Access the file name outside of process like below

```
.to("file:app/bcr-files?fileName=${header.file_name1}")
```